# how to Check Difference between data on Ignite Cache Key and Data on HBase Row-Key?

Tags: caching, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain, in-memory-data-grid

I am using Ignite as Cache Layer for HBase. I have Just Started to Integrate Apache Ignite And Apache HBase. But now I have a question that suppose I have load Initially some data i.e. A data on HBase Row-key and I do not use write Through and but using read through so when I insert some extra column on the same Rowkey in HBase at and want to get that data trough ignite then how can i get updated data in ignite Cache?

Answer (score 1):

You need update mappings in [JdbcType](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/JdbcType.html) and restart grid, otherwise Ignite wouldn't be aware of schema changes in the underlying database.